# Javascript - Updating global variable value

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to create a simple dice roller (2 dice, 6 sides). Two variables have an initial value of '1'.

A switch statement was created so that different dice images of different sides will show according to the dice variable value.

A function for generating a random number between 1 and 6 was created to simulate throwing 6 sided dice. Another function was created so that the variables will update with a random number generated when a button is clicked.

```
JS:
var die1 = 1;
var die2 = 1;

function getRandomNumber(){
 return Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
};

function rollDice(){
 die1 = getRandomNumber();
 die2 = getRandomNumber();
};

switch (die1){
case 1:
    document.getElementById("die1").src="imgs/dice-1.png";
    break;
case 2:
    document.getElementById("die1").src="imgs/dice-2.png";
    break;
case 3:
    document.getElementById("die1").src="imgs/dice-3.png";
    break;
case 4:
    document.getElementById("die1").src="imgs/dice-4.png";
    break;
case 5:
    document.getElementById("die1").src="imgs/dice-5.png";
    break;
case 6:
    document.getElementById("die1").src="imgs/dice-6.png";
    break;
};    //duplicated code for 'die2'

HTML:
<button id="roll" onclick="rollDice()">Roll</button>
```

However, when clicking the roll button, the variables are not updating and consequently, the dice images are not changing.

Can someone suggest a way this can be done? Or if an alternative take on this is required. Thanks.

Comment: That code looks valid from here...

Comment: The variables *are* updated. But the images are not changed anywhere in your code. You need to run the switch statement etc again - show us that code!

Comment: So you're saying I should run the switch statement again inside the rollDice function? Updated code reference with switch statement FYI. Thanks :)

Comment: Is the switch inside a function or in the global scope?

Comment: Its in the global scope

Comment: Then it is only executed once when the page is loaded. You must put it into a function and call it after the value of the variables are changed.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for helping this newbie! :)